# How to fix error of Overlapped address in creating Virtual Network Gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, vpn

I am trying to create a VPN and am getting error below when specifying Address pool (to 10.0.50.0/24), I don't have to use the 10.0.50.0/24 as the address pool, just wondering how to fix it with the correct address pool?

Error:

Failed to save virtual network gateway 'VPN-Point2Site'. Error: The virtual network gateway's VPN client address pool overlaps with the virtual network's address space. The overlapping address space prefixes are 10.0.0.0/16 and 10.0.50.0/24.

I tried 10.0.10.0/24, 10.0.20.0/24, 10.0.30.0/24, 10.0.10.0/16, 10.0.20.0/16, 10.0.30.0/16, all end up with the similar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, they just have to not overlap. you'd need to read about subnetting to figure out why the overlap, meanwhile you can use these addresses:

```
10.0.0.0/16
10.1.0.0/16
```

these wont overlap

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork